# Sending json string with Http GET request with HttpClient in android

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient library. And I know the way of sending the json string with POST request directly. Like:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString));
```

But how to send the same data with GET request. Since, there is no method like "setEntity(StringEntity entity)" in HttpGet class.
And I am willing to send the data without any particular key like I do with POST request.

Comment: What are you try to achieve? show with code sample. You cannot upload json string with GET httpmethod.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of NameValuePair objects and append it to the url :

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param_name_1", "param_value");
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param_name_2", "param_value");
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

String url = url + paramString;
```

Now, just do the GET Request on this `url`.

So, basically, what is happening here is that you're appending the parameter string to the url, which you can even do manually. But this is just a safer, elegant way IMO.